# AWS Toolkit for VSCode missing option to import lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I'm currently missing all additional options for importing/uploadin/deleting lambda functions using the AWS Toolkit in VSCode....the only option is to "invoke on AWS"...the functionality was there previously...I've uninstalled/reinstalled the toolkit but that does nothing.  Anyone else come across this issue previously?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...it was the version of vscode...I had 2 versions on my Mac and the older one (v1.35.0) had the issue...but everything works great on v1.55.0